# How to Control the highchart, based on external click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I need to control (show / hide) the lines of the chart from out side of the SVG.
**For example:** if I click an external link, the related chart bar or line will disappear (toggle).I am using this link for development http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

The color of the external link should have the color of the line in the chart.Already they have given the functionality inside the SVG. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide series by hide() function:

http://jsfiddle.net/vPVXF/

```
 var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].hide();
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian,But I need to give the line color to button"The color of the external link should have the color of the line in the chart"Could you please help me. (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors)

Answer (score 0):

You Can use show and hide 
You can also use `id` instead of `no` 
http://jsfiddle.net/vPVXF/17/

`chart.series[0].hide();
 chart.series[0].show();`